# Get Categories of multiple posts

Tags: categories

So I have bunch of custom posts & IDs (coming from ACF Fields). and I want to get all categories of those posts.
is there any way we can get all unique categories from array of post IDs?

Answer (score 0):

```
 global $wpdb;
 $post_ids = [1,2,3] //Array of all post ids


// get all category id's based on post ids
$result = $wpdb->get_results( " select term_taxonomy_id from " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships where object_id in (implode(",",$post_ids)) );
```